# How to use quartz framework efficiently in web application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz Framework in my Web Application (which is running in Tomcat) and it is working fine so far. I will have around 10-15 jobs that will be running in a single day couple of times.

Below is my `quartz_data.xml` file which will have all my Jobs. As of now I am showing onyly two jobs but it will have around 10-15 jobs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<job-scheduling-data
    xmlns="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/job_scheduling_data_2_0.xsd"
    version="1.8">

    <schedule>
        <job>
            <name>TestJobA</name>
            <job-class>com.sample.controller.TestJobA</job-class>
        </job>
        <trigger>
            <cron>
                <name>TestJobA</name>
                <job-name>TestJobA</job-name>
                <cron-expression>0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *</cron-expression>
            </cron>
        </trigger>
    </schedule>

        <schedule>
        <job>
            <name>TestJobB</name>
            <job-class>com.sample.controller.TestJobB</job-class>
        </job>
        <trigger>
            <cron>
                <name>TestJobB</name>
                <job-name>TestJobB</job-name>
                <cron-expression>0 0/5 * 1/1 * ? *</cron-expression>
            </cron>
        </trigger>
    </schedule>

</job-scheduling-data>
```

And below is my `quartz.properties` file which I am using as of now -

```
------------------------- Threads --------------------------- #
# How many jobs can run at the same time?
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=10

# ----------------------------- Plugins --------------------------- #
# Class to load the configuration data for each job and trigger.
# In this example, the data is in an XML file.
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.class=org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames = quartz_data.xml 
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.failOnFileNotFound = true
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
```

My question is  - Is there any other property I should be using in my `quartz.properties` file to get better performance from the quartz framework perspective. I am using it for the first time so just wanted to make sure if there is any better property I should use in my quartz.

Answer (score 0):

For best practices you can look [quartz.org/Best Practices](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/generated/2.2.1/html/qs-all/#page/Quartz_Scheduler_Documentation_Set%2Fto-bp_best_practices.html%23) and about the quartz.properties have this other link [quartz.org/Main Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/generated/2.2.1/html/qs-all/#page/Quartz_Scheduler_Documentation_Set%2Fre-main_main_scheduler_configuration.html%23)

Performance are direct conected with your environment and resources available, I propose to take a look in this documentations and choose the configurations more apropriate for your application.